# Trying to bind click action on table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, onclick

I'm trying to add a click action to the cells of an html table.

Here's my Javascript :

```
$(document)
    .ready(

function () {
    function setColor(cell) {
        var cssRed = {
            "color": '#ff0000'
        }
        var cssBlue = {
            "color": '#0000ff'
        }
        if (cell.css('color') == '#ff0000') cell.css(cssBlue);
        else cell.css(cssRed);
    }
    $('td').click(function () {
        setColor($(this));
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML

```
    <table style="text-align: center" border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which is supposed to change the color of the text within the clicked cell. I'm trying to make something similar to the grid in http://whenisgood.com

Although, for some reason, it keeps entering the `else` statement of the if (in the `setColor` method). So apparently this comparison `cell.css('color') == '#ff0000'` fails every time. What did I do wrong here?

edit: I made an alert of the `cells.css('color')` and here's the output : 
at first `rgb(11,4,0)`

and then after clicking a second time : `rgb(255,0,0)`

edit2: At first I tried assigning the colors as `blue` and `red` literally. However it wouldn't work (even if I was comparing with `blue` and `red`). I guess Javascript won't marshall `red` in Hex or RGB, right?

edit3: If you downvote, please let me know why, I'll try to update the question so it gets better.

Comment: If your comparison fails, first thing to do would be to log `cell.css('color')` to the console.

Comment: The reason if fails is because the browser does'nt return what you think it does. Try console logging the returned value and you'll see that most newer browsers returns a rgba value and not the hex value you're testing for.

Comment: After seeing the fishing downvotes, I don't wanna answer, even though I know the working! `:P`

Comment: make it a comment then. I don't even know why I got downvoted lol.

Comment: Why not using toggleClass? you can use 2 different classes and code `$(this).toggleClass('red blue')`

Comment: That's actually a good idea (I didn't know about toggleClass), I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers may return different values for colours as people have suggested.

jQuery's [`css()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css) confirms this.

> Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

**So I would suggest relying on CSS classes instead:**

***CSS***

```
.red {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.blue {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document)
.ready(
        function() {
            function setColor(cell){
                var shouldSwitch = cell.hasClass("red");
                cell.toggleClass("red", !shouldSwitch);
                cell.toggleClass("blue", shouldSwitch);

            }
                $('td').click(function(){
                    setColor($(this));
                  });
            });
```

**[Here's a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/FjKCG/1/)**

Comment: You're doing `cell.css('color', {"color":"#ff0000"})`

Comment: Dude, I don't get why you got a downvote. Even the previous deleted answer was right. `:|`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Which previous deleted answer? The one by the other user, or the earlier version of this answer? If you mean this answer, it was not at all correct. If you mean the other answer, it seemed to have the cross-browser issues, but I haven't verified this.

Comment: No, the one by another user. There were 2 answers initially and both (including yours) are right!

Comment: I'm not the answerer, but the other one apparently had some issues with the comparison... at least that's what Marko pointed out. This one is currently a correct alternative.

Comment: @user1689607 No there was no comparison issue, I removed my answer because it didn't work on netscape4 and IE6.

Comment: @undefined: Yeah, like I said, I didn't verify it. IMO IE6 doesn't constitute a cross-browser issue at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the default color of the td is red.

So just set your CSS to

```
td{color:#ff0000;}
td.highlight{color:#0000ff;}
```

and the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function setColor(cell) {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    }
    $('td').click(setColor);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/zqytM/